# insertar imagen con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenas, necesito saber como insertar una imagen dentro de mi base de datos con ajax.

Hace un tiempo aprendi a insertar de forma convencional una imagen con php. Pero ahora necesito hacerlo mediante AJAX, y me esta dando problemas.

Asumiendo que esto es mi formulario:

```
Ingresar nombre producto 
<input type="text" id="id_descripcion"><br>
<input type="file" id="id_file_imagen"><br>
<button class="btn-registrar-producto"> Registrar</button>
```

Y este el código jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn-registrar-producto").click(function(){

    var nombre = $("#id_descripcion").val();
    var file_imagen = $("#id_file_imagen").val();

    $.ajax({  
      url:"php/registrar_producto.php",  
      method:"POST",  
      data:
      {
        nombre:nombre,
        file_imagen:file_imagen,
      },
      dataType:"text",  
      success:function(data)  
      {  
        if(data=="OK"){
          alert('Datos Registrados');
        }else{
          alert(data);
        }
      }  
    });

  });

});
```

Y este mi codigo PHP:

```
<?php 
    include 'conexion.php';

        $nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];

        $imagen=$_FILES['file_imagen']['name'];
        $ruta=$_FILES['file_imagen']['tmp_name'];
        $destino='productos/'.$imagen;
        copy($ruta, $destino);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_producto (prod_nom, prod_imagen)
        VALUES ('$nombre', '$destino')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

            $mensaje = "OK";

        } else {
            echo "Ups! Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Pero me reporta el error que la variable de la imagen esta vacía y no definida.
Anteriormente lo que hacia era cubicarlo dentro de un formulario y el atributo enctype="multipart/form-data", pero como empece a estudiar ajax, asumí que ya no era necesario el **form**.

Así que, alguna forma de como solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He modificado pequeños valores en tu código, he añadido el atributo `name` en los `input`, para identificar sus valores en `PHP`, para así poder actualizar la `Base de datos`.

He añadido al formulario dos atributos, `id` y `enctype`.

Con el `id` voy a identificar el envió por `Ajax`.

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`, este valor es necesario cuando se utilizan formularios que tienen un control de carga de archivos.

También hay que tener en cuenta, que si no añadimos la `librería` de `jQuery` en nuestro documento `HTML`, dentro de la etiqueta `<head></head>`, no funcionaría el ejemplo, pequeños detalles que a veces se olvidan.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Te dejo un ejemplo:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <input type="text" name="id_descripcion" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="id_file_imagen" /><br>
    <button type="submit"> Registrar</button>
</form >
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#register-form', function() { 

       //Obtenemos datos.
        var data = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax({  
            type : 'POST',
            url  : './registrar_producto.php',
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
                  cache: false,
            processData:false,

            success:function(data) {  
                if(data=="OK"){
                  alert('Datos Registrados');
                }else{
                  alert(data);
                }
            }  
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

**PHP** (registrar_producto.php)

```
if (isset($_POST)) {       

    //Obtenemos 'ID'.
    $id_descripcion = $_POST['id_descripcion'];
    //Imagen temporal.
    $imagen = $_FILES['id_file_imagen']['tmp_name'];

    //Codigo, comprobación imagen y moveupload.

    //Codigo SQL, insertar, actualizar Base de Datos 

    //Respuesta Ajax.
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde puedo ver los "atributos" que tiene AJAX? Por ejemplo eso de type, url, data, contenteType...

Comment: Simplemente puedes obtener los valores que se han rellenado en el formulario mediante $id_descripcion = $_POST['id_descripcion']; y
  $imagen = $_FILES['id_file_imagen']['tmp_name']; Modifico la prejunta, para verlo mejor.

Comment: cómo debería recibir esa misma imagen en un controller java?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar FormData

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData

```
var nombre = $("#id_descripcion").val();
var inputFile = $("#id_file_imagen")[0];

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file_imagen', inputFile.files[0]);
data.append('nombre', nombre);

$.ajax({
  url: "php/registrar_producto.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: data,
  dataType: "text",
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == "OK") {
      alert('Datos Registrados');
    } else {
      alert(data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: En consola me aparece: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation.

Comment: Hay que añadirle `processData: false`, ya te he cambiado el código

Comment: de que forma recibo esa imagen en un controller java?