# Subir imágenes con php y jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy intentando subir un archivo con php mediante `move_uploaded_file` pero al parecer como no envío el formulario por submit y lo paso con ajax no pasa el archivo.

el formulario seria este:

```
<form id="ficha_InUsuarios" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="Agen_afoto" type="file" class="upload" onchange="LeerAfoto(this,'Agen_fotico');"/>
<input type="button" id="guardar_InUsuarios" class="botonagregar desactivado" onClick="Guardar('Usuarios','guardar_InUsuarios','InUsuarios');" value="Aceptar">&nbsp;
</form>
```

y el php este:

```
$uploaddir = '../Scripts/Imagenes/Usuarios/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['Agen_afoto']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Agen_afoto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Ha subido";
} else {
    http_response_code(500); echo 'Here is some more debugging info:'; print_r($_FILES);
} //si ha subido la foto
```

y el jquery que manda en formulario es este:

```
function Guardar(url,que,id) {
    var datos = $("#ficha_"+id).serialize();
    $.ajax({
            url: "Paginas/"+url+".php?que="+que,
            data: datos,
            type: "post",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "Nadaguardado") {  $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'No se ha guardado nada' , sticky : false, type : 'notice' });
        } else { //si esta guardado todo...
            $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Datos almacenados correctamente' , sticky : false, type : 'success' });
            $('#ficha_'+id)[0].reset();
            $('.multibuskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            $('.buskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            CancelarNuevoGrande(id);
            console.log(data);
            } },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error al guardar '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
};
```

Si paso de javascript y uso solo un submit de toda la vida, funciona perfecto, pero cuando pasa por javascript no sube la foto ¿en que me estoy equivocando?

el print_r solo pasa "array()" nada que tenga que ver con la imagen.

He probado también con FormData pero con el no me pasa ni un dato por post.

```
function Guardar(url,que,id) {
    var datos = new FormData($("#ficha_"+id));
    $.ajax({
        url: "Paginas/"+url+".php?que="+que,
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "Nadaguardado") {  $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'No se ha guardado nada' , sticky : false, type : 'notice' });
        } else { //si esta guardado todo...
            $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Datos almacenados correctamente' , sticky : false, type : 'success' });
            $('#ficha_'+id)[0].reset();
            $('.multibuskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            $('.buskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            CancelarNuevoGrande(id);
            console.log(data);
            } },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error al guardar '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
};
```

Muchísimas gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: Mira te esta(s) [pregunta/respuestas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35928/insertar-imagen-con-ajax)... O si no en las páginas oficiales: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) o [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)

Comment: @aldanux Nada, si uso FormData no pasa ni un dato por post.

Comment: Es que en la función que tienes no le estás pasando los valores... prueba primero de meterlo a mano los valores `id, url, que`... después tienes que solucionar como pasar a la función los parámetros requeridos...

Comment: Si los pasa @aldanux lo que pasa que no me pareció relevante copiarlos XD pero en el código original si estan

Comment: Vale...pues para que tu pregunta sea más clara, deberías poner el código actual y relevante que estés usando, y cualquier error que te arroje (consola, PHP)... y seguro que alguien te podrá ayudar mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resuelto.
Y para darle una vuelta de tuerca mas le he metido también un loader por si tarda mucho en subir la foto.

Aquí tenéis el código tal cual se ha quedado por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

```
function Guardar(url,que,id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Paginas/"+url+".php?que="+que,
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData($("#ficha_"+id)[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".formulario_grande_"+id).append('<div id="loader_'+id+'" class="loader-container" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>')
    },
    success: function(data) {
            $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Datos almacenados correctamente' , sticky : false, type : 'success' });
            $('#ficha_'+id)[0].reset();
            $('.multibuskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            $('.buskiselect_'+id).val(null).trigger("change");
            CancelarNuevoGrande(id);
            },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error al guardar '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
};
```

el fallo estaba en la forma de leer el FormData en vez de usar jquery he usado javascript y perfecto.