# Cómo subir varios archivos al mismo tiempo al servidor en jquery y php

Tags: php, jquery

Necesito subir varios documentos al mismo tiempo al servidor. Había intentado con lo siguiente:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="subirarchivos">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">1) Respaldo PME</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
                        <input type="file" name="respaldo">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivo">
                    </form>                                                                                                                                                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">2) Cotización</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
                        <input type="file" name="cotizacion">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivo">
                    </form>                                                                                                                                                
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">3) Nóminas</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
                        <input type="file" name="nominas">
                        <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivo">
                    </form>                                                                                                                                                
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

El php que procesa el form es:

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    $carpeta="documentos/";
    opendir($carpeta);
    $nombrearchivooriginal=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $nombrearchivoconvertido=$_SESSION['usuario']."_".microtime()."_".$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $destino=$carpeta.$nombrearchivoconvertido;
    copy($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$destino);
?>
```

El problema es que cuando doy clic en el primer "Subir Archivo", sale de la página para subir los restantes archivos. Cómo debería realizar lo que necesito?, usando Ajax?

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45231/subir-im%c3%a1genes-con-php-y-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un solo formulario, y opcionalmente tener los archivos en un arreglo con una clave:

```
    <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="subirarchivos">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">1) Respaldo PME</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="file" name="archivos[respaldo]">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">2) Cotización</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="file" name="archivos[cotizacion]">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row" style="text-align: left">3) Nóminas</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="file" name="archivos[nominas]">      
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row" style="text-align: left"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivos">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Para posteriormente acceder a cada archivo mediante su clave:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $carpeta='documentos/';
    opendir($carpeta);
    foreach( array('respaldo','cotizacion','nominas') as $clave ){
        // Es recomendable verificar si hay error
        //if( $_FILES['archivos']['error'][$clave] === 0 )   
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['archivos']['tmp_name'][$clave] 
                              , $carpeta.$_SESSION['usuario'].'_'.microtime().'_'.$_FILES['archivos']['name'][$clave]
                              );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

para hacer eso, te dejo código ejemplo en PHP y Javascript (con jQuery)

HTML

```
<form id="multiples-archivos">
    <input type="file" id="mis-archivos" name="mis-archivos"><br>
    <button type="button" id="subir-archivos">Subir</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        $("body").on("click", "#subir-archivos", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'subirarchivos.php',
                type:'POST',
                data : new FormData($('#multiples-archivos')[0]),
                contentType:false,
                cache:false,
                processData:false,
                beforeSend:function() {

                },
                success:function(dataResponse) {

                },
                complete:function() {

                }
            }); 
        });
    })();
</script>
```

archivo.php

```
//esta función la usamos para convertir el array nativo recibido a uno con un poco más de legible como el que recibes cuando mandas un solo archivo y lees con $_FILES
function fix_files($archivos) {
    $keys = array_keys($archivos);
    $count = count($keys);

    $numero_archivos = count($archivos['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i < $numero_archivos ; $i++) { 
        foreach ($keys as $key => $llave) {
            $arrContenido[$llave] = $archivos[$llave][$i];
        }
        $arrFinal[] = $arrContenido;
        $arrContenido = array();
    }

    return $arrFinal;
}

$archivos = $_FILES['mis-archivos'];
foreach ($this->fix_files($archivos) as $file) {
    $name_file = $file['name'];
    $type      = $file['type'];
    $tmp_name  = $file['tmp_name'];
    $size      = $file['size'];

    list($nombre_imagen, $extension) = explode('.', $file['name']);

    //este es tu archivo con la extensión y nombre ya dinámico listo para que lo guardes
    $nombre_archivo = uniqid() . date('YmdHis') . "." .  $extension; 
    $ruta_para_guardar = __DIR__ . '/archivos/'.$new_name;
    //si quieres el código de ejemplo para irlos guardando dentro tu misma carpeta, crea una que se llame archivos para que se guarden ahí los archivos, solo descomenta el siguiente código
    /*
    if ( move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta_para_guardar) ) :

    endif;      
    */
}
```

Comment: Y como por qué debería de hacerlo así? Qué ventajas tiene? Qué hace tu código? Recuerda que no todo el mundo acá está familiarizado con el lenguaje de programación ni la versión específica

Comment: Nadie está haciendo algo distinto a la pregunta que se está formulando, ni haciendo nada diferente, de acuerdo a cómo preguntar y cómo responder, le estoy extrayendo sólo el código necesario que debe usar y modificar para poder recibir sus archivos y procesarlos. ¿Sí lo pudiste ver?

Comment: Por favor lee también el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: En dado caso alguien tendría que indicarlo para editar la respuesta, puesto que la solución se está dando en base al mismo problema, sin tecnologías de más, ni de menos. También consulta, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Evitemos caer en discusiones en los comentarios. @FernandoUrban lo que te tratan de decir, es que solo codigo, sin ninguna clase de explicacion, no es siempre util para alguien que tiene un problema similar. A veces una explicación de determinados detalles del codigo es mas útil que todo el código entero.

Comment: @RuslanLópez evita caer en discusiones en los comentarios.

Comment: @gbianchi en ingún momento discutí, el caballero me indicó que lo explicaría si alguien realmente le indicara y yo lo hice.