# Undefined index al subir una imagen al servidor

Tags: php

Buenas, estoy topandome con este error y no estoy dando con la clave.

Notice: Undefined index: pac_foto in C:\wamp64\www\pruebas\pags\ver_foto.php on line 32

PHP.INI:

```
File Uploads activado
Max_execution_time = 300
Max_input_time = 240
Memory_limit = 128M
Post_max_size = 16M
```

fichero PHP destino

```
$pac_foto = isset($_REQUEST['pac_foto'])?$_REQUEST['pac_foto']:'';
$foto_directorio_subida = 'imgs/';
$foto_directorio_subida .= basename($_FILES['pac_foto']['name']);
$foto_tipo_archivo = $_FILES['pac_foto']['type'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pac_foto']['tmp_name'], $foto_directorio_subida)) {
        echo "Foto subida correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "No se pudo guardar la foto.";
    }
```

formulario HTML (en otro documento)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="verFoto" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
    <input type="file" name="pac_foto" />
    <input type="submit" name="pac_boton_enviar" value="Guardar Datos" />
</form>
```

He hecho var_dump de $pac_foto y me saca el nombre del fichero que estoy subiendo. Sin embargo, hago var_dump de $_FILES y me da un array vacío.

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Porqué compruebas si tienes datos en `$_REQUEST['pac_foto']` si luego utilizas `$_FILES['pac_foto']`?

Comment: Quiero utilizar el texto para otra cosa, pero visto así, verdaderamente no tiene mucho sentido. No obstante, $_REQUEST['pac_foto'] si recibe un valor, $_FILES['pac_foto'] sin embargo, no

Comment: El código se ve bien, está extraño que no te llegue el archivo. Has probado agregarle id al input del file?  `<input type="file" name="pac_foto" id="pac_foto" />`. O tal vez reiniciar el servidor, puede ser que no esté actualizado el php.ini

Comment: Pues sinceramente, no se que he debido tocar pero funciona correctamente. Ha sido ir a probar lo del id y funcionaba, lo he vuelto a quitar y seguía funcionando... Siento de veras la molestia. Muchas gracias

Comment: @JoseGonzalez realmente el atributo `id` no hace nada en tu código PHP, para obtener un valor en `PHP` se utiliza el atributo `name` como identificador, como estás haciendo en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

**Respecto a tu notice:**

> Notice: Undefined index: pac_foto in C:\wamp64\www\pruebas\pags\ver_foto.php on line 32

- Deberías iniciar dicha variable en `NULL` al inicio de tu *código
  PHP* `$pac_foto = NULL`, digamos antes de declarar dicha variable.

Respecto a tu código `PHP`, en si, se podría mejorar algunas áreas y añadirles comprobaciones `PHP` para obtener un mayor seguridad, veamos un ejemplo distinto, a ver si logro orientarte mejor.

*Un posible ejemplo:*

**HTML**

```
<form action="verfoto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
    <input type="file" name="pac_foto" />
    <input type="submit" name="pac_boton_enviar" value="Guardar Datos" />
</form>
```

**PHP** (verfoto.php)

```
<?php
//Definido y no NULL nuestro formulario.
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Comprobamos que no este vacio nuestro input file.
    if (!file_exists($_FILES['pac_foto']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo 'Por favor selecciona una imagen para continuar';
        //Rediriges si quieres al formulario.
    } else {
        //obtenemos datos imagen.
        $file = $_FILES["pac_foto"];
        $nombre_img = $file["name"];            
        $extencion_img = $file["type"];
        $ruta_temporal = $file["tmp_name"];
        $tamano_img = $file["size"];
        $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_temporal);
        $ancho = $dimensiones[0];
        $altura = $dimensiones[1];
        $carpeta = "/imgs/$nombre_img";

        //Inicio error imagen en true.
        $img_error = true;

        //Comprobaciones error (¡Esto es a gusto colores!).
        if ($extencion_img != 'image/jpeg' && $extencion_img != 'image/jpg' && $extencion_img != 'image/png' && $extencion_img != 'image/gif') {
            echo "<b>$nombre_img</b>, no es una imagen valido, un imagen con extensión valido podría ser entre (.jpg, .jpeg, .png o .gif).";                      
        } elseif($tamano_img > 300000) {
            echo"El tamaño de tu imagen <b>$nombre_img</b>, supera los 300kb permitidos."; 
        } elseif($ancho > 500 || $altura > 500) {
            echo "La anchura y la altura de <b>$nombre_img</b> supera la máxima permitida de 500px.";                   
        } elseif($ancho < 250 || $altura < 250) {
            echo "La anchura y la altura de <b>$nombre_img</b> es inferior que la mínima permitida de 250px.";              
        } else { //Imagen correcto.
            //Reseteo error en false.       
            $img_error = false;
        }

        //Verdadero imagen.
        if ($nombre_img && $img_error===false) {
            //Cargamos imagen al servidor.
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pac_foto"]["tmp_name"], $carpeta)) { 
                 echo "Foto subida correctamente";          
            } else { //Falso, imagen no cargo.          
                echo "No se pudo guardar la foto.";     
            }
        }
    }           
}
?>
```

En caso de querer implementar `AJAX` y crear formularios dinámicamente, te dejo un ejemplo de SOes: [insertar imagen con ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35928/insertar-imagen-con-ajax)