# Enviar archivo por ajax en PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy tratando de enviar correos en PHP usando mail, pero no se si el archivo se esta pasando correctamente, aqui mi codigo:

```
<script>
     var name = $('#inputName').val();
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        var message = $('#inputMessage').val();
        var asunto = $('#inputSubject').val();
         var file_data = $('#archivo').prop('files')[0];
    
    $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'EnviarForm.php',
                data:'ContactoEnviar=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&message='+message+'&asunto='+asunto+'&file_data='+file_data,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'bien'){
                        $('#inputName').val('');
                        $('#inputEmail').val('');
                        $('#inputMessage').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">¡Correo Enviado!.</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Ha ocurrido algún problema, por favor intente de nuevo.</span>');
                    }
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                    
                }
            });
</script>
```

En Enviarform.php, estoy recibiendo como "$file = $_FILES['file_data']", estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar la función mail, porque no se si el archivo lo esta recibiendo "Enviarform.php" correctamente, no se si tendrán por ahí un ejemplo que me pueda orientar para poder enviar correos con archivos adjuntos, ya he revisado algunos ejemplos, pero ahí se reciben el archivo de manera directa.

Comment: Para enviar un imagen en AJAX, debes añadir debajo de **data:** las siguientes lineas ```contentType: false, cache: false,  processData:false,```, te dejo un enlace con en ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35928/insertar-imagen-con-ajax/35948#35948

Comment: Para que puedan ayudarte mejor, sería mejor que añades tu formulario y el archivo **Enviarform.php**

Comment: Envía el formulario completo usando `formData()` así: `var formulario = new FormData($('#idFormulario')[0]);` luego agrega las propiedades que menciona @DBE . Finalmente, para saber si se está recibiendo bien la imagen haz un `print_r($_FILES);`. En el inspector de código te debería mostrar los datos de la imagen.

Comment: Gracias me ayudo :D